# Record trigger flow not working for case and email message object

Tags: visual-workflow, case, relationships, salesforce-id, emailmessage

I have working to convert the workflows into flow for the below scenario with Case and email message objects. But its does not triggering properly and am not get the result. Am not sure where  the flow conditions are struck. Anyone please check and help me to get the output for this below scenario flow.

Scenario:

The scenario was, If the "Status" is equals to **New** and incoming equals **True** in email message object and Test call (check box) in case object is **unchecked** means, that case should moves to **expected queue (Testing queue)** and case status need to update **email response received**. I mean that case owner ID should update the expected queue name (Testing queue) and case status need to update on that case.

So I setup the below condition in flow based on the requirements. But its does not works.

Condition :
(Object : email message)

Incoming = True

Status = New

Condition :
(Object : Case)

Test call **does not equal to** True

Need to Update values :
( Object : Case)

Owner ID : Testing queue.

Status : Email response received

I created the "Record Triggered flow" with entry conditions and related with ID for email message and Case. But am not aware still where I pending to add the required elements in the flow. Please anyone review and help me to complete this flow.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) Change the Flow to only be on `Created`; (2) eliminate the condition for `Status` as `Incoming = true` will suffice; (3) add condition for `Case.Test_Call = false` to entry condition and remove from the Update element; (4) add entry condition `case.Id isNull false` to only handle incoming-to-Case email messages

Comment: @cropredy - The entry element was mapped with email message object, for that reason I have setup the entry conditions as (Status & Incoming = True).  Now I able to eliminate the (Status & incoming)  and able to add the (ID isNull false) with entry condition. But how to add the condition as (Case.Test_Call = false) in entry condition, because its related to Case object . Due to email message is on entry element how do I get the Case object fields on entry level?  Also i need the final update with case object (case owner ID and case status). Please advise.

Comment: V55 allows cross object formula refs